# DNS Round Robin / A Records Priority

Tags: dns

I've set up two Mail Servers. Everything works great with replication between them.

But in my scenario there is the following problem: server1 is a powerfull machine, server2 is only a small container (just for failover).

There are for clients A DNS-Records like imap.server.xy which point to both servers.

I want the clients to use primarily the strong machine. I have tried adding to the A-Record for the strong server a priority.

Unfortunately this doesn't work, clients don't prefer the stronger server, they also use the small container.

Is there any way to use priority in A-Records with DNS-Round Robin?

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/) would be a better place to ask this I think.